# Error Code Selenium Element Not Visible Web Form

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate my search for companies using buzzfile.com, but the search input field keeps causing Selenium to throw an error at me of "not visible", I've tried implementing wait time but still it's not working. I've also tried searching for the field by "name" as well as by its xpath '//*[@id="searchTerm"]'. I'm using Python 2x, Selenium package, website: www.buzzfile.com/Basic and my search query is for "company name" field, example text "Opus Solutions". I've listed the error code below, with an image of the full traceback. Can someone please help me with this?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import re
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://www.buzzfile.com/Home/Basic')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

search_form2 = driver.find_element_by_id('searchTerm')

search_form2.send_keys('Opus Solutions')
```

Error:

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
>     (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540469 (1881fd7f8641508feb5166b7cae561d87723cfa8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64)

[Full Error Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6WNk.png)

Answer (score 0):

The id `searchTerm` is not a unique selector.
Try using `findByClassName` of `ByCssSelector` where classname(s) are `form-control searchTerm nav-search-term-text-home ui-autocomplete-input` for the left input field and `form-control searchTerm2 nav-search-term-location-text-home ui-autocomplete-input` for the right search input field.
I hope you can pass the anti-bot defence presented when the `'http://www.buzzfile.com/Home/Basic'` page is loaded.